# In nextjs, How do I pass postData into my layout?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do I give a layout component `postData`?
In my example, I want my layout (ArticleStyle2) to get the `postData` and populate itself with the data.  Not sure if this is best practice or whatever, so open to suggestions, pretty new to nextJs and react.

**[id].js**:

```
export default function Post({ postData }) {

  return (
    <div>

      { postData.themeOne ? (

        <ArticleStyle2 {...postData}>
........
```

**articleStyle2**:

```
export default function ArticleStyle2({ children, props }) {

    return (
 
<div>

<main>{children}</main>

</div>




    )
}
```

Comment: `<ArticleStyle2 data={postData}>` would be a proper use. You could then retrieve it with `props.data` inside your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the function signature `ArticleStyle2({ children, props })`, you'd pass `props` into your layout component like this:

**[id].js**

```js
<ArticleStyle2 props={postData}>...</ArticleStyle2>
```

Then you can use them in your layout like this:

**ArticleStyle2.jsx**

```js
<p>{props.themeOne}</p>
```

Here's a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mendel-c8hbtz

Comment: thank you!  Do you know where the docs are for that "<ArticleStyle2 props={postData}>...</ArticleStyle2>" part?  I was trying to find that, everyone was suggesting "data={}" but that didn't work

Comment: @Snorlax No specific docs, it's just matching the property names being passed in. For example, if you had used `<ArticleStyle2 data={postData}>` instead, then use that same name in `ArticleStyle2({ children, data })` and `<p>{data.themeOne}</p>`. If it was `foo={postData}`, then it'd be `ArticleStyle2({ children, foo })` and `<p>{foo.themeOne}</p>`, etc.

Comment: Oh I see, is this syntax nextJS exclusive?

Comment: @Snorlax It is not; it's React. See [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).